# Efficiently creating a large interaction matrix (billions to trillions of cells). AWS Glue PySpark ETL

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, etl, aws-glue

I'm attempting to pivot data and generate a user-item interaction matrix for modelling. 
I have been executing this as an an AWS Glue Spark job.

In my sample I have 53,000 customers who have purchased over 1,000,000 different products. This will result in an interaction matrix with ~53billion cells to populate. It looks like this:

```
clientID  ProductID  Purchased
1         1          1
1         2          1
2         1          1
2         3          1
3         2          1
N.B. Purchased is a tinyint dummy indicating if a customer bought a product. 
There are no rows for when a customer has not purchased.
```

Currently I've been using the following code:

```
pivot = df.groupby("clientid").pivot("productid").agg(max("Purchased"))
```

Now, I've already allowed this job to run for >2 days with 150 nodes (quadcore 16GB nodes) and still have nothing to show for it. This is making me very conscious of the cost of this, especially given this is a sample of the population and in the future this will need to scale up to over a million customers.

Can someone confirm if there is a more computationally efficient way to perform the above and explain this to me?

Thank you for any assistance ahead of time. If you need any further details let me know.

Comment: @mazaneicha That could indeed be done to help with the sample computation, but won't work in the long term as the full dataset has roughly clientIDs = ProductIDs

Comment: sorry, got excited by 53K clients vs 1M products... If you're expecting your client base to grow to MMs as well, I guess it is better to start looking at `glom()`ing the partitions and building Sparse martices for analysis.

Answer (score 0):

For `N` rows of `clientid` there will be same number of rows of `productid`. Then am I correct to say that for the follwoing query

```
pivot = df.groupby("clientid").pivot("productid").agg(max("Purchased"))
```

in the absence of the optimization, the table would be `N²` and then this would be shrunken by the aggregating operation.

So, why not aggregate first (maybe it can't be max anymore but say `sum` or `int(mean()`) and then pivot? In the absence of optimization this should make a difference. Apart from that, there is nothing much we can do with such a straight forward but a huge pivot.

Comment: Forgive me if I'm misinterpreting your solution but I do not think this will reduce the scale of the computation. The "Purchased" variable is just a dummy so the min/max can only ever be 0/1.

Comment: I see. In that case, you are not misinterpreting my solution but hey, you have terribly huge matrix with lot of sparsity. In that case, instead of the pandas `pivot`, I would much prefer to write a parallel C++ code where I represent my matrix by the indices `(i, j)` corresponding to non-zero values. Then you have really neat parallel C++ algorithms for matrix factorization. I am sorry I can't provide the whole solution though because of my personal time constraints but I can try to write a python routine which could serve as a pseudo code.

Comment: May I know what are the mathematical requirements for this `user-item interaction` matrix and what and how do you plan to use it for downstream application? Will it transform to `user-by_user matrix` or `item-by-item matrix`?

Comment: So a few things. Firstly, thank you for your response.
So I'm using a Pyspark `pivot` not pandas. Which should parallelise across the 150 DPUs i've allocated well. It will also apply `NULL` where there are no values as opposed to 0 so the size of the matrix should be minimised

Comment: The use case for this matrix is to generate the usual user/item vectors associated with matrix factorisation and then enhance these from embedded user/item vectors that we will generate using autoencoders. The system will then be used to recommend new items to users for purchase.